# How long should I wait before watering my beheaded echeveria stem?

Tags: watering, succulents, propagation

I recently (yesterday) beheaded an echeveria plant that had grown leggy. The leafy upper part is currently set aside, forming a callous and (hopefully) roots. I can find plenty of information about how to replant and when to start watering that part of the plant, but if I want to give the beheaded stem a chance to form new blooms, how should I care for it? Should it be on essentially the same watering schedule that the plant was on before beheading?

Answer (score 1):

Getting growth from a stump is not assured, even if you do everything right (I assume the base has no leaves. If it does, just treat it normally and it'll be fine). I hope it was actively growing before you cut it

If it's outside, I'd put it in an area with less harsh, filtered light. If it's inside, I'd just do normal culture. As for water, just water it normally. The soil should dry out between waterings